# Delete a specific record from File in Java

Tags: java, file-handling

I am trying to delete specific record from File, but every time I run it deletes the whole file. Can anyone please tell where the bug is?

I have added temp db and also the methods are correct. There is some what problem with the logic of the loop. Kindly help me. Thank you!

```
 public void DeleteRecordByID() throws IOException {
                Scanner strInput =  new Scanner(System.in);
                String ID, record;

            File tempDB = new File("employees.txt");
            File db = new File("employees.txt");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( db ) );
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( tempDB ) );

            System.out.println("\t\t Delete Employee Record\n");

            System.out.println("Enter the Employee ID: ");
            ID =  strInput.nextLine();

            while( ( record = br.readLine() ) != null ) {
                if( record.contains(ID) ) 
                    continue;

                bw.write(record);
                bw.flush();
                bw.newLine();
            }

            br.close();
            bw.close();
            db.delete();
            tempDB.renameTo(db);
    }
```

Comment: You need to be precise with your question. Where exactly is the problem, what exactly is the problem.

Comment: O.k the problem is when I try to delete the data by using specific ID, it deletes my file. The file is removed not the specific data.

Comment: You are only showing **parts** of your code here. Lazily formatted code by the way. You want us to spend our time to help you - so you make that as easy as possible. Starting with taking the 1 minute it takes to properly format your input (instead of dumping zillions of useless empty lines on us).

Comment: @GhostCat How about you do not help others at all. Because your comment was rude. So called programmer. lol

Comment: So far your question didn't receive much positive feedback, did it? I gave you feedback why that is. Instead of seeing that as a chance to *learn* something so that your input might receives better reception you decided to go defensive. You don't like being told that your input looks lazily formatted? Well, then improve that part. Again: you want **us** to spend **our** time to help you. You see, that **preview** window exists for a reason! How would you think about a coworker that comes by and drops such input on you? You probably wouldn't like that. But I am rude - for telling you the truth?

Answer (score 1):

You should use two different file names, one for reading and one for writing.

Comment: I have two different files. DB and TEMPDB

Comment: no, you have two File variables, but they both point to the same file `employees.txt` on your filesystem.

Comment: Correct observation. But that basically boils down to "simply typo error". And as it reads now, your "answer" looks much more like a mediocre comment.

Comment: Answer corrected: different files -> different file names. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! @jurez My code is actually fixed. That is how real programmers help.

Comment: @SayianFatim And "real" programmers know to accept helpful answers. And they take each and any chance they get to *learn* something to improve their actions.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a temporary file in which you write the data. After that, you can delete the original file, then rename the temporary file to the original.